# Encrypt PDF during Crystal Report Exporting using itextSharp

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, itext

I have crystal report. I want to export it to PDF. At the same time I want to Encrypt it using iTextSharp.

This is my code:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF File|*.pdf";

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string filepath = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
    crd.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, filepath);
    var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filepath);
    PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open), PdfWriter.STRENGTH128BITS, "pass", "pass", PdfWriter.AllowScreenReaders);
}
```

I am getting following

> Error:
>   "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

What is the problem? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Your actual problem is that you are trying to write to a file while you are reading from a file. Generally speaking these two operations shouldn't be done at the same time. @reckface solution is probably the best path to go down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try exporting to stream, then encrypting the memory stream, rather than working with the exported file. I use PdfSharp and here's my workflow.

```
// create memory stream
var ms = report.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)
// Then open stream
PdfDocument doc = PdfReader.Open(ms);
// add password
var security = doc.SecuritySettings;
security.UserPassword = password;
ms = new MemoryStream();
doc.Save(ms, false);
```

**EDIT**

```
// I don't know anything about ITextSharp
// I've modified your code to not create the file until after encryption
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string filepath = saveFileDialog1.FileName; // Store the file name
    // Export to Stream
    var ms = crd.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
    var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    ms.Position = 0; // 0 the stream
    // Create a new file stream
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ms); // Load pdf stream created earlier
        // Encrypt pdf to file stream
        PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, fs, PdfWriter.STRENGTH128BITS, "pass", "pass", PdfWriter.AllowScreenReaders);
        // job done?
    }
}
```

Comment: No Its Showing following Error: An unhandled exception of type 'iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException' occurred in itextsharp.dll

Additional information: PDF header signature not found.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Sorry, it should be ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat

Comment: Good Work buddy..Its Done..Thank You Very Much